# weird behavior with grid faces

Tags: faces

I'm trying to make a low poly hills/terrain and ran into some weird behavior with the corner faces

I make a 10x10 grid of size 10

[image: grid]

I select a square of 4 faces and I press G + Z + mouse move up to move these faces up 1m

[image: select]

the NE and SW corners look correct

[image: corners1]

But for some reason the NW and SE corners are different and don't slope downwards on the corners

[image: corners2]

I tried using edge slide but the same thing happens.

Does anyone know what is going on or how I can fix this and have all corners be the same?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@thibsert's explanation is completely correct, but to also answer the question of how to fix this:

Use the modifier *Triangulate*.

This will triangulate the quads according to your settings, not randomly.

Here is an example with *Shortest Diagonal*:

[image]

And here an example with *Longest Diagonal*:

[image]

...Of course, you can also edit the mesh manually and add appropriate edges so that it is built exactly as you want it.

Comment: Thx, I didn't know that :)

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*I don't have any solution, but here is at least an explanation.*

A graphic card can only display Triangles. When Blender seems to display a Quad, it is in fact divided into two Tris.

The thing is, you can divide an 'ABCD' Quad into two pairs of Tris : ABC + ADC, or ABD + BCD.

That's not an issue if A,B,C and D are co-planar : both pair will look like a flat quad face. But if they aren't, they will look like two distinct triangles, and that's what append to your corners.

If you Triangulate (Ctrl+T) your grid before moving the hill up, the result will be exactly the same, but the reason should look more obvious !

[image]

Please note that both are, geometrically speaking, perfectly valid. That's why I can't give you a solution : that is not a "problem"...

Comment: It all makes sense now.  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @PeterHearn A thank you is expressed here with an upvote ;-) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

To add to Quellenform's and Thibsert's answers, you could extrude up your 4x4 quads, it will give a better topology:

[image]

Comment: Yes, in terms of topology, that would actually be the correct answer.